# Ionic 4 action sheet: Accessing returned value in other component

Tags: ionic-framework, promise, ionic4

I have a 1 service and 1 component and I'd like to keep the action sheet functionality in the service and then pass the result to the component.  For some reason I cannot access the returned value.  [Here are the docs to the actionsheetcontroller](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/action-sheet).

```
// photo.service
async selectImageSheet() {
  const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
    header: "Select Image source",
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Load from Library',
        handler: () => {
          this.imageSource = this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
          return this.imageSource
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Use Camera',
        handler: () => {
          this.imageSource = this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
          return this.imageSource
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

And in my component I do the following:

```
//component
selectImage() {
    this.photo.selectImageSheet().then(() => console.log(this.photo.imageSource))
    console.log(this.photo.imageSource)
}
```

Neither of the `console.logs` appear in the component.  I've tried returning a promise with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `onDismiss` - check the doc - https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/action-sheet

```
const actionSheet = await actionSheetController.create({
  header: "Sheet Header",
  buttons: [ ]
});

await actionSheet.present();

let result = await actionSheet.onDidDismiss();   
console.log(results)
```